# CiviCase - cannot save

Tags: civicase

I am part way through setting up CiviCase. All went well until all of a sudden I get this error message:

*"Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved"*

Is there a limit to the number of timelines that can be set up? I am wondering if that is what might be causing the problem.

Otherwise, why am I getting this grief all of a sudden?

Added info as requested:

I am using Civi 4.5.5 and Drupal 7.34. In addition to the standard timeline, I had an additional four. It was when trying to add a fifth timeline that I got the offending error message.

I tried to break the demo but couldn't. Went up to six timelines (although with only token activities so it was not an exact replica).

Not sure if a mix of the volume of activities and numbers of timelines was the issue. –

Comment: Can you share more please about the specifics of your situation? What version of Civi, CMS, how many timelines, any other particularities of your Case?

Comment: Please edit your question to give more specific steps to create this error. Can you try to reproduce the error with the same steps on [demo.civicrm.org](https://civicrm.org/demo)?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am using Civi  4.5.5 and Drupal 7.34. In addition to the standard timeline, I had an additional four. It was when trying to add a fifth timeline that I got the offending error message. I tried to break the demo but couldn't. Went up to six timelines (although with only token activities so it was not an exact replica). Not sure if a mix of the volume of activities and numbers of timelines was the issue.

Comment: On earlier versions of Civi, we experienced issues saving new cases if I didn't first delete the automatically assigned case role.